# Como ejecutar correctamente una funcion importada desde otro modulo?

Tags: python, python-import

Esto esta en el menu del modulo main (con menu o sin menu pasa lo mismo, asi q el menu no es el problema)
`

```
        print("Ha seleccionado carga aleatoria. Aguarde un momento")
        create_vec(16)
        random_vec(vec)
        order_vec(vec)
        print("Ahora mostraremos los datos generados")
        time.sleep(seg)
        show_vec(vec)
```

`

Esto esta en el otro modulo

```
def create_vec(n):
vec = [None] * n
return vec



def random_vec(vec):
# Nombres aleatorios que decidimos. Al haber 16 nombres, siempre van a ser los mismos
# a menos que el usuario elija carga manual.
name_list = ["The Hunger Games", "X6tence", "Soda Stereo", "Shootgaming", "Halo", "Enigma",
             "U2", "What Remains Of Edith Finch", "Monogatari", "Durarara", "Darks", "A + B",
             "Neo", "Malvinas", "COVID", "Serbia"]

world_rank = list(range(1, 100))

for i in range(len(vec)):
    name = random.choice(name_list)
    cont = random.choice(continent_list)
    rank = random.choice(world_rank)

    # Para que no se repitan, los eliminamos de la lista para la proxima seleccion aleatoria
    # Continente no necesita removerse porque si se puede repetir
    name_list.remove(name)
    world_rank.remove(rank)

    # Lo agregamos al arreglo
    vec[i] = Teams(name, cont, rank)
```

Tengo un modulo de funciones, muy bonito y todo. En ese modulo tengo basicamente una funcion que crea un vector, y varias que trabajan usando ese vector (ejemplo: una funcion que lo ordena). Pude corroborar que todas las funciones andan perfectamente dentro del modulo funciones. Pero cuando quiero hacer uso de esas funciones en el modulo principal, a pesar de que puedo importar bien, y pareciera no tener problemas, no anda.

create_vec(16)

load_vec(vec)

La funcion vec solamente crea el vector vacio y lo retorna.

La funcion load permite cargar datos dentro de ese vector

Si yo ejecuto ambas funciones dentro del modulo original, funcionan sin proble,a
pero cuando quiero usarlas en el otro modulo dice: "Unresolved reference 'vec' "
Basicamente vec no existe en esta funcion. Lo que me intriga es si la funcion create vec, tiene el return, por que la funcion load_vec no me acepta el vector (se llama vec por cierto) como argumento?

Hago nuevamente enfasis en que dentro del otro modulo andaba.

Para importar estoy usando "from functions import *"

Perdon si no esta presentada la pregunta como corresponde, es la primera vez que posteo aca. Claramente estoy recien empezando a aprender python

Muchas gracias desde ya, y perdon si la pregunta es algo tonta.

Comment: Nadie nace aprendido, no te preocupes. Pero te recomiendo que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y añadas el código a tu pregunta. Especificamente el de esas funciones. Es imposible saber qué está pasando si no podemos ver el código

Comment: Gracias. Ya lei el articulo y corregi la pregunta. Agregue el codigo de la funcion crear y de la funcion random, ademas de la llamada desde el modulo principal

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido,

De tu pregunta deduzco que el **módulo que contiene las funciones** se llama **functions.py** y el main lo podemos llamar como queramos, main.py sería un nombre apropiado. Deduzco también que, como no dices que te esté dando error de indentación, es porque cuando has copiado el código has olvidado indentar lo que se encuentra dentro de las funciones con 4 espacios, de modo que quedaría así:

```
def create_vec(n):
    vec = [None] * n
    return vec



def random_vec(vec):
    # Nombres aleatorios que decidimos. Al haber 16 nombres, siempre van a ser los mismos
    # a menos que el usuario elija carga manual.
    name_list = ["The Hunger Games", "X6tence", "Soda Stereo", "Shootgaming", "Halo", "Enigma",
                 "U2", "What Remains Of Edith Finch", "Monogatari", "Durarara", "Darks", "A + B",
                 "Neo", "Malvinas", "COVID", "Serbia"]
    
    world_rank = list(range(1, 100))
    
    for i in range(len(vec)):
        name = random.choice(name_list)
        cont = random.choice(continent_list)
        rank = random.choice(world_rank)
    
        # Para que no se repitan, los eliminamos de la lista para la proxima seleccion aleatoria
        # Continente no necesita removerse porque si se puede repetir
        name_list.remove(name)
        world_rank.remove(rank)
    
        # Lo agregamos al arreglo
        vec[i] = Teams(name, cont, rank)
```

Adicionalmente, entiendo que has puesto sólo una porción de **functions.py** y que falta la definición de varias funciones (*order_vec y show_vec*) y el objecto *Teams*.

Una vez hechas las aclaraciones, pasamos al error:

**Error:**

Cuando llamas a la función create_vec no le estás asignando la salida a ninguna variable, por tanto cuando el código intenta llamar a la siguiente función:

```
random_vec(vec)
```

la **variable vec no existe** para solventarlo debes guardar la salida de create_vec en una variable que depués pasarás como **argumento** en la llamada de *random_vec*, tal que así:

**Solución:**

```
vec = create_vec(16)
random_vec(vec)
```

**Apunte:**

El nombre de la variable cuando llamas a la función no depende del nombre que le pusiste al argumento de entrada cuando definiste la función es decir, valdría:

```
mi_nombre_favorito = create_vec(16)
random_vec(mi_nombre_favorito)
```

Saludos